# AWS Signed Requests are not working on Google App Engine using java.net.URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

All,

I am developing a simple Java web app using Play (v 1.2.4) framework.  The application performs a signed ItemLookup request using Amazon's Product Advertising API.  I am deploying the application to Google App Engine (GAE), wherein lies my problem.

**Details:**
In local/testing mode, the AWS signed request works perfectly using both apache.commons.httpclient and the simpler java.net.URL.  After deploying to GAE and finding that an HTTPClient connection was not supported b/c of the usage of SocketConnection, I modified the AWS calls to use **java.net.URL**.  The AWS ItemLookup requests not only continued to work in local mode, but I no longer received any exceptions in Google App Engine (GAE).

**Problem:**
However, the problem I am having is that all of my AWS ItemLookup requests come back with a message that the signed signature does not match what AWS was expecting.  See the actual message at the end of this question.

Therefore, I'm rather unsure of what is happening.  I am logging the requests that go out from both local mode and GAE and the format of the signed URL request does not appear to have any problems.  I've checked and double/triple-checked; my requests are going out with the correct AWS key. These calls work with the same keys in local mode, therefore should they not work via GAE as well?  For example, a sample request on GAE (with AWS key/tag stripped out):

```
    SIGNED REQUEST=http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=<removed>&AssociateTag=<removed>&ItemId=B0051VVOB2&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2012-03-04T00%3A52%3A23Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=<removed>
```

So, I'm starting to think that the **HmacSHA256** on GAE may be working incorrectly, or perhaps I need to use a different algorithm on GAE?

Perhaps I've run up against some sort of issue with using AWS on GAE?  I could really use some help on this problem.

Thank you for your assistance.

**ItemLookup Response Error (example):**

```
    <ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
    <Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestID>aa42318e-9c2c-4f04-9905-670866223bc5</RequestID>
    </ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

Comment: This is not particularly relevant to the play framework. I've removed the tag. 

If you think that the hashing method is working differently local and on GAE, create a small page/servlet/whatever that creates a hash for a given static input, then compare between local results and GAE results and report a bug on GAE.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I am considering just moving to Amazon EC2.  It's such a more flexible environment to develop for when you do not have to be concerned with the constraints of GAE.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I since moved away from GAE and run inside of AWS exclusively.  Sorry.